# Windows Forms DialogResult

Tags: c#, winforms, dialogresult

in the following code I want to get the dialog result of a Form but it's not saved to my variable... why?

My code:

```
public void xyz() {
    var dialogResult = new DialogResult();
    if (booleanVariable) {
        var form1 = new Form1();
        form1.ShowDialog();
        dialogResult = form1.DialogResult;
    }
    else {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();
        dialogResult = form2.DialogResult;
    }

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK) {
        ...
    }
}
```

At the and of my `Form1` and `Form2` i set the `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`.
At the end of the process my variable `dialogResult` is `DialogResult.None`, why?

Comment: `var dialogResult = new DialogResult();` is a bit strange. The `DialogResult` type is an enumeration. You shouldn't need to use `new` at all.

Comment: Cody: This may be the attempt at correct typing due to `var`. It seems like they don't know how to declare variable types explicitly.

Comment: No this is a attempt to declare the variable globaly because i can't acces it if I declare it within the if.

Comment: That's non-responsive to the issue. You can't use `var` to declare a variable unless you're assigning to it at the same time because otherwise the static type cannot be deduced. Since there's no reason to `new` an enum type, you can't use `var` to declare it. Just write: `DialogResult dialogResult;`

Comment: Ok I recognized my fault :) thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void xyz() {
    var dialogResult = booleanVariable ? new Form1().ShowDialog() : new Form2().ShowDialog();

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to modify this with your `IF` Statement:

```
DialogResult var;
Form2 qwerty  = new Form2();
var = qwerty.ShowDialog();
MessageBox.Show(var.ToString());
```